# How to create sub domain using virtualization in CakePHP

Tags: subdomain, cakephp-2.0, virtual, routes

How to create sub domain using virtualization in CakePHP using a dedicated router?

Send to address

sabz.domain.com/blog/posts/view/10

to

domain.com/blog/posts/view/10/sub:sabz

Comment: Please rephrase your question as it is too confusing to understand if you want to create the redirect in CakePHP or within your router

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in routes.php

$subdomain = substr(env("HTTP_HOST"), 0, strpos(env("HTTP_HOST"),"."));

```
if ($subdomain != 'domain') {
  Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'homes', 'action' =>'userview', 'pass' => $subdomain));
}
```

And change according to you need.